# Colon symbol does not show up on Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

This is a very strange thing happening to my Jupyter notebook. When I press the ':' symbol on my keyboard, Jupyter notebook does not recognize it as part of python code, but when I enter it in commented code, the colon shows up. There is nothing wrong with my keyboard, colon shows up everywhere other than Jupyter notebook.

I tried to switch browsers, check shortcuts and update Conda, but nothing works.

Does anyone know what is going on? I'm also on a mac.

For example:

Colon shows up in commented code

```
# !jt -r :
```

Colon disappears when uncomment the code

```
!jt -r
```

Colon, ':' , does not show up when I type it in the code. It is not even replaced by a space; Jupyter notebook doesn't have any reaction when I type colon.

Comment: send screenshot to have a clue

Comment: Please go to __HELP > Keyboard Shortcuts__;   Check if you have edited any shortcut

Comment: @AndreNevares I checked, colon was never used by any shortcut.

Comment: @LuisAlejandroVargasRamos I added more detail